# Classical wave equation from fermions

Tags: waves, fermions

Every time there is a classical wave equation, the underlying system is bosonic. For example, em waves are made from photons, sound from phonons (technically quasi-particles), etc.

What would be the classical wave equation corresponding to a fermionic particle? Intuition says that it would be very different. For example, take the fundemental mode standing wave in a 1m box. The wave equation admits solutions of any amplitude, which means there is no limit to the number of particles *with a 2m De Broglie wavelength* that can be stuffed into the box. Fermions don't allow this, so if we replace photons with, for example, "massless" neutrinos, we would get something different in the classical limit.

Note: you can make neutrinos "massless" by using such a high frequency that the energy>>rest mass.

Comment: related:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66681/classical-geometric-interpretation-of-spinors

Comment: The [Dirac equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation). Note that fermions are anticommuting variables, so you can't really represent them by ordinary numbers, but there is a theory of "Grassmann numbers" that works.

Comment: See section 18.2 of this pdf:  http://www.physics.ox.ac.uk/users/iontrap/ams/teaching/rel_C_fields.pdf‎  From the intro:  *"In the whole of this book up to and including this chapter, all fields mentioned are classical
fields. The electromagnetic field has been shown to be a tensor field. We have sometimes
invoked scalar fields for illustrative purposes. **In this chapter the idea of a classical spinor field
will be introduced."***

Comment: The boudaries conditions could be different. For instance, in the calculus of (1-dimensional) Casimir Energy for fermions, one impose anti-symmetric conditions, which lead to semi-integer conditions for acceptable energies $E' = (n+ \frac{1}{2})E'_0$(instead of integer conditions for bosons $E = n E_0$)